# como puedo bloquear la pantalla debajo de un FAB en flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, aplicación-movil, floating-action-button

[Tengo el siguiente menú en un Floating Action Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAGH4.png)

Lo que quiero hacer, es atenuar la pantalla debajo de ese widget (FAB menu), mas en general, poner una especie de capa negra atenuada debajo de los elementos que conforman ese menu